# Why can't Gmail have an Archive mailbox?

Tags: gmail

What is the reason that gmail has no archive mailbox (unlike Outlook)? Is it because that would make it too easy to find archived (including accidentally archived) mail?
It seems perverse.
Is there any way of getting rid of this archive (alternatively known as 'lost forever') feature?

Answer (score 3):

When you archive a message in GMail, it isn't "lost forver" - it's in the All Mail section of the application, and it's also findable by searching. In addition to browsing All Mail in time order, you can search by sender, receiver, time windows, email size, the presence of attachments (or lack of attachments) and more.

Answer (score 1):

The archive button does one thing and one thing only. It removes the inbox label.

So any message that has been archived still has the other labels attached to it. And everything except SPAM has the hidden label "All Mail".